# Search engine of Italian buses

Tags: online-resources, public-transport, buses, italy

Is there one search engine of scheduled buses in Italy, where I can search timetables of any bus company? Or, if not all of them, at least significant number of companies.

Comment: Local, long-distance, or both?

Comment: The best would be both, or long distance (between eg. major cities)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every city has its own local bus company with timetables and lines:

- **Milan** local buses: [Milano ATM](http://www.atm.it/it/Pagine/default.aspx)
- **Rome** local buses: [Roma ATAC](http://www.atac.roma.it)
- **Florence** local buses: [Firenze ATAF](http://www.ataf.net)
- **Bologna** local buses: [Bologna ATC](http://www.atc.bo.it)

Take the train could be a good choice to travel across Italy:

- [Trenitalia - national train company](http://www.trenitalia.com/)
- [Italo - new company with a lot of offers but less destinations](http://www.italotreno.it/IT/Pagine/default.aspx)

Last but not least, consider Google Maps search. It supports public transit in its "Got Directions" pretty well.

Enjoy your trip!

Comment: P.S. I had to ask you to google since I don't have (yet) the reputation to post more than 2 hyperlinks. Sorry for that!

Comment: You can post the links as text, and a high-rep user will take care of this.

Comment: lol, don't trust Google Maps: coverage is very very spotty. [This is certainly one way to go from Milan to Bergamo](http://i.imgur.com/2W2Kw.png), for example, but I wouldn't recommend it to my worst enemy.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer concerns local buses and recommends trains for long-distance journeys. However especially for travel to the south of Italy, this is not always the most convenient option.

To the best of my knowledge there is no search engine that covers all long-distance bus lines of Italy. Typically I proceed as:

- Search on [iBus](http://www.ibus.it/)
- Search with [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/)
- Google for further direct bus links using "autobus/bus/pullman *departure city* **destination city**", e.g. "pullman Roma Matera". It is recommended to use Italian city names here, as not all services may be advertised in English.
- Maybe you are lucky and your departure or destination city has a bus terminal that lists departures/arrivals, this could give a good overview of existing lines. Search for "stazione pullman *city*".
- If you know someone from the area (especially students), you could ask them how they typically travel - I discovered some bus lines this way that I was not aware of.

Then take the best result you get from these searches and proceed to booking either via the search engines above or from the bus company directly (often slightly cheaper).

Answer (score 1):

Italy is also covered by [Google transit](http://www.google.com/transit). I don't know how good it is for Italy, but for my home town it is quite good.

Comment: Coverage is exceptional, or in other words it is the exception rather than the rule. I wish I could change this :(